# Redirecting me to Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

Tags: linux, tomcat, shibboleth

So I set up shibboleth. In my configuration file I set the location to /loginaction.do. However when the user logs in it redirects them to /Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST. Why is this happening? Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up a `homeURL` somewhere? Without seeing any configuration, it's difficult to say anything.